# Selecting attributes of a filtered nodeset in XPath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to learn XPath syntax. I'm using the w3schools example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_pricenodes_high

..which is based on the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8""?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title la="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

The example selects the title of books having a price greater than 35. I wanted to play with this example and select the category names instead of titles. So, I tried this:

```
/bookstore/book[price>35]/@category
```

And, as you can see by testing it yourself on that site, it produces no output. What am I getting wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your example doesn't have any books with a price > 35. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is OK. But since you're dealing with attribute nodes and not elements, you have to adjust the code that prints the result. Change the lines

```
document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

to

```
document.write(nodes[i].nodeValue);
document.write(result.nodeValue);
```

and you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Aha! I almost pulled my hair out, not being able to get such a simple example to work! Thanks!